# vue-router authentication error "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, vuejs2, vuex

im creating a vue/vuex and quasar based dashboard. but in this error i got and stuck with this authentication.
also i need proper way when user already logged login page also need to redirect dashboard.

login process is seems working perfect. when login page add credentials and login it response the token and bind to the status perfectly, but it not redirected to the dashboard, it fires the following error message(i have attached the screenshot)
im expecting expertise guide or any other solution for this u guys suggest.
[image]
**Router index**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from '../store'
import routes from './routes'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Router instantiation;
 *
 * The function below can be async too; either use
 * async/await or return a Promise which resolves
 * with the Router instance.
 */

// export default function (/* { store, ssrContext } */) {
const Router = new VueRouter({
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
  routes,

  // Leave these as they are and change in quasar.conf.js instead!
  // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
  // quasar.conf.js -> build -> publicPath
  mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
  base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE
})

Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.getters['auth/isLoggedIn']) {
      next({ name: 'Dashboard' })
      return
    }
    next('/login')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

export default Router
```

**Routes**

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: () => import('pages/Login.vue') },
  {
    path: '/app',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
    name: 'App',
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') },
      { path: 'user', name: 'User', component: () => import('pages/User.vue') }
    ]
  },

  {
    path: '*',
    component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')
  }
]

export default routes
```

**Vuex auth**

```
import Api from '../api'
// import { axios } from 'vue/types/umd';

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
    user: null
  },
  getters: {
    isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token,
    user (state) {
      return state.user
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_TOKEN (state, token) {
      state.token = token
    },
    SET_USER (state, user) {
      state.user = user
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async signIn ({ commit }, credentials) {
      const response = await Api().post('/token', credentials)
      const token = response.data.token
      const loginuser = {
        username: response.data.user_display_name,
        email: response.data.user_email
      }
      commit('SET_TOKEN', token)
      commit('SET_USER', loginuser)
    },
    signOut ({ commit }) {
      return Api().post('/logout').then(() => {
        commit('SET_TOKEN', null)
        commit('SET_USER', null)
      })
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is your `beforeEach` guard:

```
Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.getters['auth/isLoggedIn']) {
      next({ name: 'Dashboard' })
      return
    }
    next('/login')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Your app enters into an infinite loop because of the redirection to route named 'Dashboard'. When it's entering Dashboard, beforeEach is called and redirect to 'Dashboard'. Then it call beforeEach and so on over and over again until it raises the exception

Answer (score 0):

This kind of rules in the guards are typically to prevent unauthorized users to access some routes, and you have that. The problem is, just like Andrea commented, that you are always redirecting to the same page, and when you reach that page the beforeEach will run again, creating the loop.

Typically, when a user is authorized you simple execute next() to let the user move forward, otherwise you send him/her to wherever you want, like "/login".

What I will recommend you is that instead of using a guard to send your user to a certain initial page you use Dashboard as your default route using the route redirect property:

```
{ path: '/app', redirect: '/dashboard' }
```

Comment: Thank You Luis.. let me do the changes and will see..